# MKMapView, how to calculate the elevation in meters?

Tags: ios, dictionary, mkmapview, elevation

How can I calculate the elevation (altitude from the sea level) of the center of my mapview (which is not the user current location), in meters?

We can see this indication for example on Google Earth :

[image: Google Earth image]

Comment: Are you trying to get the altitude of the ground that is in the center of your map view, or the altitude that someone would be at floating over your map to see the same view as your map view?

Answer (score 3):

What about

```
mapView.camera.altitude
```

@property(nonatomic) CLLocationDistance altitude

The altitude above the ground, measured in meters.

Availability    iOS (7.0 and later)

Declared In MKMapCamera.h
Reference   MKMapCamera Class Reference

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know Apple does not provide an API for determining the altitude of a coordinate. Google has an Elevation API that can be used for this. You can access it through an HTTP interface and get the altitude of a location as an JSON response.

Issue the following request to get the elevation of 39.7391536,-104.9847034:

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/elevation/json?locations=39.7391536,-104.9847034&sensor=false
```

Then you'll get a JSON response like this

```
{
   "results" : [
      {
         "elevation" : 1608.637939453125,
         "location" : {
            "lat" : 39.73915360,
            "lng" : -104.98470340
         },
         "resolution" : 4.771975994110107
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

The full Elevation API is documented here https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/elevation/

Answer (score 1):

[CLLocation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocation_Class/) comes with the altitude of the current loction

Comment: Thanks but I don't want the current altitude of the user location. I need the elevation which correspond to the current zoom level of the map.